# Adjust MKCircle radius with slider iOS

Tags: ios, slider, geometry, readonly

I am trying to create an MKCircle around a dropped pin and have the radius adjustable with a UISlider.

In my slider method that calls when the user changes the value of the slider. I attempt to simply reference the circle and say:

```
circle.radius = slider.value;
```

However I receive the error: "Assignment to readonly property."

Thank You!

Comment: The `radius` property is readonly. See the docs for `MKCircle`. You'll have to create a new `MKCircle` with the new radius.

Comment: Can you possibly show me how I would do that?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use an IBAction, like this

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChange:(UISlider *)sender {
float value = [sender.value floatValue];
circle = nil; 
CLLocationCoordinate2D center; //Add your CLLocationCoordinate2D
circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:center radius:value];
[self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as posted. This: float value = [sender.value floatValue];... results in an error. However I was able to get the slider to adjust the radius of newly placed circles with the slider by basically storing the value of the radius with a float. However I am still having trouble dynamically updating the radius as I slide.

Comment: Why not? Can you tell me what's happening, that way I will be more than happy to help

Comment: So I did this... - (IBAction)slide:(UISlider *)sender
{
    [mapView removeOverlay:cir];
    
    rad = slider.value;
    
    cir = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:circleCenter radius:rad];
    
    [mapView addOverlay:cir];
    [circleArray addObject:cir];
} cir is an MKCircle that can also be added by pressing a button. circleCenter is just a variable that finds the center of the screen. It makes a new circle with the right sized rad but im making a new circle each time so the screen is pretty laggy/sketchy.

Comment: I cant just say cir.radius = slider.value I get the error "Assignment to readonly property." Do you know anyway around this. The var cir represents an MKCircle.

Comment: No you cant, you can dealloc the MKCircle and reallocate it programmatically like this                                   circle = nil;                                 CLLocationCoordinate2D center; //Add your CLLocationCoordinate2D circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:center radius:value];

Comment: Okay, thanks. That works but its really glitchy this way. Basically every time the sliders value is changed the old circle is eliminated from the view and the memory and a new one is instantiated. Is there a way to simply just change the radius of the originally instantiated circle and update it on the map when the slider is called? Clearing & making a new one every time doesn't look very smooth.